# Will installaling from USB HDD harm files in that disk?

Tags: installation, external-hdd

I downloaded Ubuntu installer on my portable HDD, and I have a question. Will files be deleted from my portable HDD if I install Ubuntu directly from it(i plant to install it on my PC HDD, not on my portable HDD).

Comment: How are you planning to install?

Comment: well i plan to plug in my HDD in my laptop and mount ubuntu from it(just in the same way you would from USB)... im just worried because of my files that are on HDD(everything is on my portable HDD, and it would be very bad if it got lost)

Comment: How are you going to mount?  What IS are you running right now?

Comment: im running windows xp. but problem is my xp gets freezing all the time, and there is some important data on my HDD(in my PC, not the portable one) that is need, so i planned to instal ubuntu next to xp and than save my date before i reboot my windows... i can't stat my XP now(it freezes before welcome screen)

Comment: @Fichom, What Ubuntu installer you downloaded, give that link in your question. also state the way you planned to install. Is it via making your USB bootable or something other?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop the big orange "Start download" button on the right... yeah i guess i planned to make my USB bootable... how do i do it anyway? and if i make it bootable, do i loose all my data? should i transfer ubuntu installer on CD? im really not familiar with this stuff, but i want to instal ubuntu on my PC, so i can get data from my HDD on PC that i cannot acces because my XP froze... so basicaly i want to instal ubuntu on my PC(but can't via xp because i can't start it)

Comment: Your best bet is to burn the ISO onto a CD, and boot from it. Download and use [free ISO burner](http://pcsupport.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=pcsupport&cdn=compute&tm=5&f=20&su=p504.6.342.ip_&tt=7&bt=1&bts=1&zu=http%3A//www.freeisoburner.com/).  And if you need more help, we'll be here.

Answer (score 1):

Download the universal USB installer from [this link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). Run that tools from any Windows PC. direct it to the location of the ISO file you downloaded. then go next, to make the USB bootable.

**And never check the format checkbox**. If you do so, all will be deleted.

See the image below, *(image credit goes to the site owner)*.

[image]

The message is, Don't check on the `Format I:\ Drive` checkbox.

Comment: Note though that this can still delete current files, if it has to reformat the drive in order to make it usable for Ubuntu. Depending on how you want to install it (i.e. directly to the drive), you may have no choice but to format.